# A discussion about the definition of derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> **Definition**
>
> Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R^m$; let $f:A\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$. Suppose $A$ contains a neighborhood of $a$. Given $u\in\Bbb R^m$ with $u\neq 0$, define
> $$
> f'(a;u):=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+tu)-f(a)}t
> $$
> provided the limit exists. This limit depends both on $a$ and on $u$; it is called the directional derivative of $f$ at $a$ with respect to the vector $u$.

So I would like to discuss about the hypothesis for which $A$ contains a neighborhood of $a$ that is I ask if this neighborhood must be a neighborhood in $\Bbb R^m$ or rather in relative topology of the subspace $A$. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supposed to be an open ball surrounding $a$. The vector $u$ might be in any direction, so the idea is that for $t$ small enough $a+tu$ is still within $A$ where $f$ can be applied.

I think you are asking if the "neighborhood" is an open set in the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$, or if it can be an open set in the topology of $A$ that comes from intersection with the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But if it were the latter, why bother "supposing" $A$ contains a neighborhood of $a$? That would be the case always. So it's the former, and again, the idea behind that is as in the above paragraph.

Comment: I'm saying $\{a\}\subset \text{some open ball}\subset A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. And the ball is a full, open ball, not just the intersection of some open ball with $A$.

Comment: So it has not sense to calculate the derivative in the boundary points?

Comment: So substantially I ask how to explain what Munkres state [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831687/two-function-cant-have-the-same-derivative-in-a-not-open-set).

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro You could calculate some directional derivatives in boundary points. Not the full derivative.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Okay, so what it is wrote [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831687/two-functions-cannot-have-the-same-derivative-at-not-interior-points) is probably a typo? What can you say about?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro The boundary of half space is an exception, we have all directions, but only from side $t>0$, so we take limits from the right in $\Bbb R$ to define the derivative there.