# Two functions cannot have the same derivative at not interior points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

What discuss below is a reference form the text "Analysis on Manifolds" by James Munkres.

[image]

First of all we observe the the interior of $U$ is not empty when $U$ is too: for details see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829452/the-interior-of-open-set-in-a-convex-set-is-not-empty).
So by the first definition to we can suppose that the derivative of $\alpha$ exist only in $\text{int}(U)$ but strangerly Munkres state that $D\beta(x)=D\alpha(x)$ for any $x\in U$. So how explain this statement?
Could it be a typo? So could someone help me, please?

Comment: He's talking about smooth extensions to sets open in $\Bbb R^k$. There's no contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, I don't completely understand what you want say. Could you expleain better, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: Are you noticing he talks about $U’$, which is open in $\Bbb R^k$?

Comment: Yes, I noticed.

Comment: But when $x\in\text{Bd}(U)\subseteq U'$ what means $D\beta(x)=D\alpha(x)$? This is my problem.

Comment: What can you say about? Could you give me some clarifications?

Comment: No, he's *defining* $d\alpha(x)$ to be $d\beta(x)$, which makes sense, and asking you to show that and two extensions $\beta$ and $\gamma$ will have the same derivative at $x$.  But your comment below is the crucial point: There is no problem with derivatives of $\alpha$ at $x$ in directions that live in $\Bbb R^{k-1}=\partial \Bbb H^k$. And for the direction $e_k$, we can compute the one-sided directional derivative of $\alpha$ in the *positive* $e_k$ direction. This is what $d\beta(x)(e_k)$ must be.

Comment: Okay, so in this **particular** case we can exted the definition of derivative at the boundary points and Munkres did this tacitly, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I properly understand what your problem is, but Munkres nowhere explicitly writes down the equation $\ D\alpha(x)=D\beta(x)\ $, or implies that $\  D\alpha(x)\ $ exists at a boundary point of $\ U\ $ in any sense *other than* what he is here showing *can be taken to be its definition* there. The point of his Lemma $23.2$ is that if $\ \beta_1\ $ and $\ \beta_2\ $ are *any* $\ C^r\ $ extensions of $\ \alpha\ $ to an open subset of $\ \mathbf{R}^k\ $, then $\ D\beta_1(x)= D\beta_2(x)\ $ for all $\ x\in U\ $.  Thus, even though the normal definition of $\ D\alpha(x)\ $ cannot be used to define it on the intersection of $\ U\ $ with the boundary of $\ \mathbf{H}^k\ $ , you can nevertheless *take its definition* to be $\ D\beta(x)\ $ there, where $\ \beta\ $ is any extension of $\ \alpha\ $ to an open subset of $\ \mathbf{R}^k\ $.

Comment: Munkres states that if $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are $C^r$ extensions of $\alpha$ to two open subset $U_1$ and $U_2$ in $\Bbb R^k$ then substantially $D\beta_1(x)=D\beta_2(x)$ for $x\in U$ and not in $H^k$ where $U$ is the domain of $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for picking up the error..  The fact that $\ \alpha\ $ was not defined on the whole of $\ \mathbf{H}^k\ $ had slipped my mind.  I have now corrected  my answer.

Comment: So actually using Munkres definition it has not sense to calculate the derivative of $\alpha$ at the boundary points of $U$, right?. Anyway in this case it seems possible to calculate the limit $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\alpha(x_0+he_j)-\alpha(x_0)}{h}$$ for any $j=1,...,n$ and for any $x_0\in\text{Bd}(U)$ so in this **particular** case we can think to extend the definition of derivative of $\alpha$. What do you think about?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say in your first sentence, but it's not necessarily true that you can calculate that limit at *any* point of $\ \text{Bd}_{\mathbf{R}^k}(U)\ $. You can, however, certainly do it at those points of  $\ \text{Bd}_{\mathbf{R}^k}(U)\ $ which do not also lie in $\ \text{Bd}_{\mathbf{H}^k}(U)\ $—that is, at those points of $\ U\ $ lying in the boundary of $\ \mathbf{H}^k $.

Comment: I wanted say what to follow. So $\text{Bd}_{\pmb{R}^k}(U)=\{x\in U: x_k=0\}$ and fortunately if $x_0\in\text{Bd}_{\pmb{R}^k}(U)$ then $0$ is a limit point of the set $H_j:=\{h\in\pmb R:(x_0+he_j)\in U\}$ for any $j=1,...,n$ so that we can calculate the quantity $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\alpha(x_0+he_j)-\alpha(x_0)}h$$ for any $j=1,..,k$ but in the case $j=k$ we have necessarly $h\rightarrow 0^+$ and when the latter quantity exists we can call it the derivative of $\alpha$ respect $x_j$ extendig in this **particular** case the definition of derivative that Munkres gave above, that's all.

Comment: I only paraphrased what you said in your answer adding some topological observations. Do you see any mistake in what I said?

Comment: My answer had an error which I noticed and then corrected after I had read your paraphrase.  But, yes, I think I now understand what you meant, and, if so, I don't any mistakes other than my own.

Answer (score -1):

This, "First of all we observe the the interior of U is not empty when U is too".  That is not true,  the singleton set U= {x} is non-empty but its interior **is** empty.

Comment: In our case $U$ is open and instead the singletons are not open.

Comment: Oh, I missed that!  But in that case, your statement is trivial!  The interior of an open set **is** that open set.

Comment: Sorry, but my statement is not trivial. Munkres state that $U$ is open in $H^k$ but is **not** open in $\Bbb R^k$. So if $U$ is open in $H^k$ then there exist an open set $V$ in $\Bbb R^k$ such that $U=V\cap H^k$ so that the Munkres statement is equivalent to state that $\text{int}(U)=\text{int}(V)\cap\text{int}(H^k)=V\cap\text{int}(H^k)$ is not empty that is $U\subseteq\text{cl}\big(\text{int}(H^k)\big)$ and this it is clearly not trivia I think.

Comment: I think the ambiguity of the term "interior of $\ U\ $" has caused some communication problems here.  The interior of $\ U\ $ *in* $\ \mathbf{H}^k\ $ *is* $\ U\ $ just as [user247327](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/247327/user247327) says.  However, I presume by "the interior of $\ U\ $" in your statement you mean the interior of $\ U\ $ *in* $\ \mathbf{R}^k\ $, which, of course is not the same thing (as you have explained).